# Why is my selenium script not locating the element?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to create a signup script for https://www.cvs.com and I keep running into the same issue no matter what I try.

Here is my current code:

```
    Options = Options()
    Options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),
                          options=Options)
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(10)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/cvs-email-lookup//cvs-form/div/form/div/cvs-text-input/div/input').send_keys(catchall)
    time.sleep(2)
```

The error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Documents/cvs-account-gen/main.py", line 122, in <module>
    main(fname, lname, catchall, password, Options,url)
  File "/Users/Documents/cvs-account-gen/main.py", line 116, in main
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/cvs-email-lookup//cvs-form/div/form/div/cvs-text-input/div/input').send_keys(catchall)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 742, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 348, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/cvs-email-lookup//cvs-form/div/form/div/cvs-text-input/div/input"}
  (Session info: chrome=120.0.6099.129); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
Stacktrace:
0   chromedriver                        0x00000001006944dc chromedriver + 4162780
1   chromedriver                        0x000000010068c664 chromedriver + 4130404
2   chromedriver                        0x00000001002e3bc0 chromedriver + 293824
3   chromedriver                        0x000000010032a040 chromedriver + 581696
4   chromedriver                        0x0000000100369ab0 chromedriver + 842416
5   chromedriver                        0x000000010031d6bc chromedriver + 530108
6   chromedriver                        0x000000010031e930 chromedriver + 534832
7   chromedriver                        0x0000000100659e08 chromedriver + 3923464
8   chromedriver                        0x000000010065e3dc chromedriver + 3941340
9   chromedriver                        0x0000000100642038 chromedriver + 3825720
10  chromedriver                        0x000000010065ef3c chromedriver + 3944252
11  chromedriver                        0x00000001006346f4 chromedriver + 3770100
12  chromedriver                        0x000000010067b980 chromedriver + 4061568
13  chromedriver                        0x000000010067baf8 chromedriver + 4061944
14  chromedriver                        0x000000010068c2e4 chromedriver + 4129508
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000018436d034 _pthread_start + 136
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000184367e3c thread_start + 8
```

I tried finding it by ID, XPATH, and the css sector, each time I run into the same issue.

Here is what I tried:

ID : "cvs-form-0-input-email" and "email-input"
XPath : "//*[@id="cvs-form-0-input-email"]"
Full XPath : "/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/cvs-email-lookup//cvs-form/div/form/div/cvs-text-input/div/input"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not using a VPN as this website is not opening outside of USA. A different screen appears for the countries other than USA. See below:
[image]
Also you can use  **EC.presence_of_element_located** to avoid any error because of time outs.
Argument in **WebDriveWait** are the number of seconds, you want your scrapper to wait for the element to appear.

```
      element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, your xpath))
        WebDriverWait(chrome_driver, 100).until(element_present)
```

Comment: I am in the usa and I am not using a vpn, I will try the solution you provided and will let you know!

Thanks